# Tried to do a complete fresh install of Sierra. "Permission Denied" when I go to Install

Tags: macos, install, permission

So I wiped my computer at work using the disk utility. I went to install the OS again and when I select the drive and hit "install" I get "The operation couldn't be completed. Permission Denied"

[image]

When I search for this problem it looks like most people aren't reinstalling the OS and just installing a program so their issue seems to be they are not using an Admin account or what not.

With my issue I'm not exactly logged in to any account and don't know how to give myself permission.

Does anyone have any ideas to fix this issue?

Heres a link to a [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/70whut/tried_to_do_a_complete_fresh_install_of_sierra/) thread I made where some one tried to help me out so you can see what I've tried. Theres also some more screen shots in that thread.

Edit: I should add that I tried restarting and holding <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>to do an Internet recovery but when do it takes me back to macOS Utility. I assume as soon as I and it goes to that progress bar which makes me unable to hold <kbd>Command</kbd> to choose a boot location. I do have macOS installer on a USB drive but again, when I restart and hold <kbd>Option</kbd> it does the progress bar. I do have another Mac and a Thunderbolt cable but I'm not quite sure of the process to use another computer to install the OS. I'll be searching that now.

Comment: I restarted and held Shift, Option, Command R and it actually brought me to Internet Recovery... its doing its thing right now.

Comment: No dice, I get a pop up saying "macOS could not be installed on your computer. "volume contains macOS or OSX Installation Media. Quit the installer to restart  your computer and try again."

Comment: You can't install onto OS X Base System, that's the Recovery volume. From Recovery, if you don't get a choice of volumes to install on, go to Disk Utility & check you have a formatted GUID/HFS+ volume you should be installing to.

Comment: I only see Fusion Drive and OSX base system https://imgur.com/a/IvBvS . Also now all i have on the screen is a black background with White circle with a cross through it :S restarting brings me back to that circle.

Comment: Ahh... you appear to have a 1TB recovery partition... not what you really want.  All I could suggest would be to boot to Internet recovery & reformat the drive as a single regular partition;  then install to that & it will create a new, correctly-sized recovery as it does it.

Comment: I got to internet recovery but after it was done it said "macOS could not be installed on your computer. "volume contains macOS or OSX Installation Media. Quit the installer to restart your computer and try again." when i restarted I got a black background with White circle with a cross through it when I restart it brings me back to that circle.

Comment: You need to run Disk Utility from Internet Recovery, not Install OS X.

Comment: ah gotcha. How do I bypass this circle thing on my screen to get to that state?

Comment: If you can get to an installer from Internet Recovery, you have already got past the point you'd have the 'it's busted' sign. Cmd/opt/R at the chimes should bring you to a recovery suite which includes Disk Utility.

Comment: is it a "work" computer ? was it "managed" ?

Answer (score 3):

This one should help it

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7860429

Needed to erase and rename the Drive to Macintosh HD

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Please edit your answer with the key points in the link and use the link as supporting documentation and/or for further reading.

Comment: I can't believe this worked.

Answer (score 2):

**Only do this if you have a backup and are allowed to delete everything on the internal drive**

If you have access to another mac computer, you can download the app to install mojave (or whatever the right version you want is), and then use this guide to create a bootable usb drive:

[Official Apple Guide](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372)

Once you have created the installation media, boot into macOS while holding Option. An icon will come up that says install macOS and then go to disk utility. Erase the disk and reformat it to APFS. If this doesn't work, go to the terminal and use `diskutil list` to find the right disk, and `diskutil eraseDisk APFS macOS disk3`. Make sure to replace the disk3 with the correct disk identifier that you got with `diskutil list`.

After you have prepared your internal disk, go back to install it, and it should work.

The reason this works I think is because the installation is not booting off of the internal drive, but in internet recovery it is booting off the internal drive.

Answer (score 1):

If you updated your OS to High Sierra and you want to downgrade to Sierra, make sure the partition format is Mac OS Extended not AFPS. Mine was AFPS and that's what caused the error.

Answer (score -3):

**The operation couldn't be completed permission denied**, I Am Facing the same Problem. And I Find what the issue, it's HDD Cable connector not working properly. Please replace & try again hope problem is resolved.
without any Issue,

Comment: The asker is trying to install Sierra, not sure how your answer helps.