# Permission denied when trying to reinstall macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, mojave, permission, recovery

So this is what happened. When using my Mac Mini I tried to open Opera browser and suddenly it said something like “Can’t open this application. Contact the administrator of this computer”. I don’t remember the precise text of the message.

I restarted the Mac and it went into an infinite loop of restarts showing me “Your computer restarted because of a problem” on each restart.

So I launched the recovery mode and tried to reinstall the os. I selected Macintosh HD and then it told me instantly “operation cannot be completed. Permission denied”. I tried running First Aid in the Disk Utility but it didn’t help. Googling doesn’t give me a clue as well so I need your help guys.

UPDATE: This is what I've got after running `ls -la /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/` command:

```
total 40
drwxr-xr-x   36 root  wheel   1152 Jul 31  2019 .
drwxr-xr-x    4 root  wheel    204 Feb  9 09:31 ..
-rw-rw-r--    1 root  admin  14340 Jan 31 20:16 .DS_Store
d--x--x--x    9 root  wheel    288 Feb  8 22:55 .DocumentRevisions-V100
dr-xr-xr-t@   2 root  wheel     64 Mar 12  2013 .HFS+ Private Directory Data?
drwxr-xr-x    2 root  wheel     64 Mar 12  2013 .PKInstallSandboxManager
drwxr-xr-x@   2 root  wheel     64 Feb  5  2019 .PKInstallSandboxManager-SystemSoftware
drwx------    5 root  wheel    160 Mar 12  2013 .Spotlight-V100
d-wx-wx-wt@   2 root  wheel     64 Apr  4  2015 .Trashes
srwxrwxrwx    1 root  wheel      0 Jul 31  2019 .dbfseventsd
----------    1 root  admin      0 Aug 17  2018 .file
drwx------   47 root  wheel   1504 Feb  9 00:54 .fseventsd
drwxr-xr-x    2 root  wheel     64 Nov  4  2018 .vol
drwxrwxr-x+ 100 root  admin   3200 Feb  8 23:22 Applications
drwxr-xr-x    3 root  wheel     96 Feb 22  2019 Developer
drwxr-xr-x+  65 root  wheel   2080 Nov  4  2018 Library
drwxr-xr-x    2 root  wheel     64 Nov  4  2018 Network
drwxr-xr-x@   5 root  wheel    160 Oct 24  2018 System
-rw-r--r--@   1 501   staff    238 Feb 20  2019 Test.hpp
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel     49 Aug 31  2013 User Information -> /Library/Documentation/User Information.localized
drwxr-xr-x    6 root  admin    192 Nov  4  2018 Users
drwxr-xr-x@   3 root  wheel     96 Feb  8 23:12 Volumes
drwxr-xr-x@  37 root  wheel   1184 Oct 24  2018 bin
drwxrwxr-t    2 root  admin     64 Nov  4  2018 cores
drwxr-xr-x    3 root  wheel     96 Jun 29  2016 data
dr-xr-xr-x    2 root  wheel     64 Nov  4  2018 dev
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root  wheel     11 Nov  4  2018 etc -> private/etc
dr-xr-xr-x@   2 root  wheel     64 Jan 11  2017 home
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    313 Aug 18  2018 installer.failurerequests
dr-xr-xr-x@   2 root  wheel     64 Apr  4  2015 net
drwxr-xr-x@   3 root  wheel     96 Jul 30  2016 opt
drwxr-xr-x    6 root  wheel    192 Nov  4  2018 private
drwxr-xr-x@  64 root  wheel   2048 Nov  4  2018 sbin
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root  wheel     11 Nov  4  2018 tmp -> private/tmp
drwxr-xr-x@   9 root  wheel    288 Oct 24  2018 usr
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root  wheel     11 Nov  4  2018 var -> private/var
```

and this is the results of running `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         499.9 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (disk image):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +2.1 GB     disk1
1:                  Apple_HFS OS X Base System        2.0 GB     disk1s1

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +499.9 GB   disk2
                             Physical Store disk0s2
1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            397.5 GB   disk2s1
2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 44.9 MB    disk2s2
3:                APFS Volume Recovery                509.8 MB   disk2s3
4:                APFS Volume VM                      8.6 GB     disk2s4

/dev/disk3 (disk image):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:                            untitled               +5.2 MB     disk3

/dev/disk4 (disk image):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk4

/dev/disk5 (disk image):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk5

/dev/disk6 (disk image):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk6

/dev/disk7 (disk image):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk7

/dev/disk8 (disk image):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk8

/dev/disk9 (disk image):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk9

/dev/disk10 (disk image):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:                            untitled               +12.6 MB    disk10

/dev/disk11 (disk image):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:                            untitled               +4.2 MB     disk11

/dev/disk12 (disk image):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk12

/dev/disk13 (disk image):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk13

/dev/disk14 (disk image):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk14

/dev/disk15 (disk image):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk15

/dev/disk16 (disk image):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk16

/dev/disk17 (disk image):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:                            untitled               +6.3 MB     disk17

/dev/disk18 (disk image):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:                            untitled               +6.3 MB     disk18

/dev/disk19 (disk image):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk19

/dev/disk20 (disk image):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk20
```

Comment: Open Terminal (menubar > Utilities > Terminal) and enter `ls -la /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/` and then `diskutil list`. Please post the results here. In Recovery Mode you should still be able to access https://apple.stackexchange.com/ (with Safari and your credentials). Try to add the results as formatted text.

Comment: @klanomath Thank you for your response. I've updated my question with the results of running the commands

Comment: I just wanted to exclude the following mess: [Tried to do a complete fresh install of Sierra. “Permission Denied” when I go to Install](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298968/tried-to-do-a-complete-fresh-install-of-sierra-permission-denied-when-i-go-to) > [Help, restored Macintosh HD to OS X Base System](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7860429). But your partition layout and root content looks good...

Comment: Hi I am facing the exact same issue, have you been able to resolve yours? Thanks!