# Permission denied reinstalling MacOS from internet

Tags: high-sierra, install, permission

I've been getting lots of prompts to repair `Library` in MacOS High Sierra, and every time I type in my password to allow it, it does nothing. I then tried `` disktuil resetUserPermissions / `id -u` ``, which also failed. So, I booted to internet recovery using <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and tried First Aid, that kept failing with error code 8 and problem -69842. I therefore decided to just reinstall MacOS. I tried that and got "The operation couldn't be completed. Permission denied".

I've using Windows and linux tools that will allow me to scan for bad sectors to determine if the disk is actually bad; I can't seem to get such a thing working on MacOS. I'm also not familiar with tools that can't repair some permissions or FS structure but the disk can still be booted from and has most things working fine. I feel like there is a scan and recovery tool like those I've used on Windows and linux that can just fix this up.

Any suggestions on how to get things working again without deleting the volumes and starting over?

Comment: Is this the screen you see when permission denied is presented to you? https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/298968/5472

Comment: Close @bmike, I'm thing to install on to "Mac HD".

Comment: Good, hopefully you don’t need to erase the volume to get a clean install going

Comment: I did @bmike :(